# How do I keep my Google Maps API_KEY secret on a react-native Android app?

Tags: google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

[Google's documentation for using react-native-maps calls](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/a7b8517771c3633e073e6c464bd3d80ee1500637/docs/installation.md) for placing your API_KEY in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Sharing that project on Github would expose your key for the entire world.

Is there a preferred way to configure the system so that the API_KEY can be kept locally?

And since the entire point of using react-native is to be cross-platform, is there also a way to configure this for iOS?

Comment: I did find [this](https://cuneyt.aliustaoglu.biz/en/hide-your-api-keys-from-androidmanifest-xml-using-local-properties/), which I think answers the question for Android, but I feel like there should be a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, the answer turns out to be:

In the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="${googleMapsApiKey}"/>
```

Then in the android/build.gradle, add to defaultConfig:

`manifestPlaceholders = [googleMapsApiKey:googleMapApiKey]`

and above that, at the top level:

def googleMapApiKey = System.getenv("googleMapsApiKey")

Set the environment variable in your shell:

`export googleMapApiKey = AI.......`

In a comment above I found an [article](https://cuneyt.aliustaoglu.biz/en/hide-your-api-keys-from-androidmanifest-xml-using-local-properties/). It turns out to be slightly incorrect; it omits the necessary line about [manifestPlaceholders](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables).